# How do I configure 5.1 audio?

Tags: sound

I have 5.1 audio system and I have on board sound ac 97(in windows I install Soundmax for this), In ubuntu I have configured this 5.1 audio.

All the channels are working fine, the problem is my rear right is replaced with center channel and center channel is replaced by rear right, the sub-woofer is making better sound than windows but when I run the sound test it says rear centre for the subwoofer, I've test many ways but couldn't correct it.

Is there a way to hack any file and correct this, plz can anybody help me, I am a newbie for linux(ubuntu 10.10 installed and working, no problems with sound on 11.10!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the Alsa PPA might have a fix. It's worth a try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-iquik/alsa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It might work for you as you're using an older version.

Comment: Thanks, but when i run this command i get this- Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~iquik-team/+archive/alsa: HTTP Error 404: Not Found  -why? and should i upgrade my ubuntu?, last time my full update make my boot skin changed, and performance was noticeably slow, and i had to reinstall ubuntu, do i miss anything

Comment: Sorry about that. My computer died. It was due to a typo. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks bro, that helps a lot, this is the first time I have to request help form ask Ubuntu, but I didn't think i could solve my problem this quick!, thanks again, it's Wonderful to have advices from u guys(Ubuntu's Humanity to others really works!)